# Dynamically instantiate Player class in a loop

Tags: python, list, loops

I am making a simple Python game. I have a text file with the following on each line:

```
player name, player IP, player health, player items
```

I have a loop which goes through each line in the file and get the variables for each player (each line in the text file is a player).

I have a class called `Player`, I need one instance of this for each player.I wish to have a list which contains all the instances of Player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sven has a good answer but you can even do away with the first line and just do

```
config = [line.split(',') for line in open("config")]
```

Or as you may want to actually instantiate the players:

```
config = [Player(line.split(',')) for line in open("config")]
```

If you're going to be doing a lot more csv configs for your game, look into the csv module.

Comment: I'm not asking how to split the data out of the file - i've already done that. I'm asking how i can instantiate my class for each player in a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the update, so would the config variable be an array where config[0] = first Player object, config[43] the 44th player object, etc.

Comment: Don't use a loop, use a list comprehension as above.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use the map function to call the constructor and expand what you've read in the config file as the parameters of the instantiation:

```
players = map(lambda tuple_args: Player(*tuple_args), (line.split(',') for line in open("config")))
```

or simpler using list comprehension:

```
players = [Player(*(line.split(','))) for line in open("config")]
```